# Jooq - Date column with time

Tags: java, jdbc, jooq

In my oracle database, in a table, I have a Date column. I fetch it using jooq, its a simple select query. The jooq fetches the column value, but without time. Have I missed any configurations?

Comment: I think this is related to Date/Time/Timestamp mapping. Is the DB clearly a full timestamp and is the mapping read as java.util.Date as opposed to a java.sql.Date as the latter have no time component

Comment: The column, CREATE_TS, is of type DATE. In table class generated by the jooq, 
    public final org.jooq.TableField<com.mgage.amex.tables.records.AmexComplaintRecord, java.sql.Date> CREATE_TS = createField(
   "CREATE_TS", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.DATE, this);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, jOOQ maps Oracle's `DATE` column to `java.sql.Date` and `TIMESTAMP` to `java.sql.Timestamp`.

If you want to use Oracle's historic `DATE` semantics (date-time with seconds precision), then you can have jOOQ generate `java.sql.Timestamp` columns also for `DATE` columns using the `<dateAsTimestamp/>` code generation flag:

```xml
<!-- Generate java.sql.Timestamp fields for DATE columns. This is
     particularly useful for Oracle databases.
     Defaults to false -->
<dateAsTimestamp>false</dateAsTimestamp>
```

Details here:
http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/

This answer was also given on the [jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/MFg1ETs6nnk)

Comment: As you now have deprecated the use of `dateAsTimestamp`, it is not so clear to me how to achieve the above using bindings only. I tried to create and use a binding (implementing `Binding<Date, Timestamp>`) similar to your  `org.jooq.impl.DateAsTimestampBinding`, but this results in loosing the time component of the Oracle date. So as of now, I'm stuck with using the `dateAsTimestamp` flag.

Comment: @ErlendKristiansen: Yes, that deprecation was a bit premature as there isn't an easy-to-implement replacement (yet). See also [my answer on the user group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/MFg1ETs6nnk/l-HuNazeAwAJ). For the time being, I suggest using the deprecated flag.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers I could find for this issue on the web were more or less related to code generation, but I was working on a framework project and didn't want to couple my code to any specific databases.

The problem I had was, JOOQ cut off the time part from the data of `DATE` column when calling `Record.getValue()` methods.

According to [JOOQ's doc](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.5/manual/sql-execution/fetching/resultset-fetching/), I worked it around by getting the value of `DATE` column from underlying `ResultSet` instead of using `Record.getValue()`.

Sample code:

```
ResultQuery<Record> query;
Cursor<Record> cursor = query.fetchLazy(fetchSize);
cursor.fetchOne(new RecordMapper<Record, Map<String, Object>>() {
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> map(final Record record) {
        for (Field<?> field : record.fields()) {
            record.getValue(field, converter);
            if ("date".equals(field.getDataType().getTypeName())) {
                resultSet resultSet = cursor.resultSet();
                try {
                    Timestamp ts = resultSet.getTimestamp(field.getName());
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // ......
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: The SQL standard `DATE` type, as well as the JDBC `java.sql.Date` type do not support any time information - unlike Oracle. Prior to jOOQ 3.5, there has been the `<dateAsTimestamp/>` code generation flag, and with jOOQ 3.5, you can also specify [`org.jooq.Binding`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/) to bind your Oracle `DATE` type to the most appropriate Java type

Comment: @LukasEder Thank you for the comment! I did take a look at the binding feature that comes with JOOQ 3.5, but seems it is available only when I am using JOOQ's code generator, is that true?

Comment: Hmm, no, you can use `Binding` also without the code generator via [`DataType.asConvertedDataType(Binding)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DataType.html#asConvertedDataType-org.jooq.Binding-). Of course, using the code generator makes this step a bit more convenient...